# odoo 9 theme installed in addson are missing from app

Tags: odoo-9

I install odoo on a virtualbox using vagrant (ubuntu/trusty32)

I set up odoo using the following:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty32
in Vagrantfile
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.7"
vagrant reload 


vagrant ssh
sudo su
wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
sudo -u postgres createuser -s odoo
```

found the addons directory using:

```
# cd /etc/odoo/
# cat openerp-server.conf
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
```

created a theme in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons using https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/themes.html

where is says:

```
Installing your theme
To install your theme, you just place your theme folder inside addons in your Odoo installation.

After that, navigate to the Settings page, look for your theme and click on the install button.
```

But the theme doesn't display in settings (http://55.55.55.7:8069/web#menu_id=86&action=78) or in the app list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. activate developer mode: https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/how-can-i-activate-the-developer-mode-83
2. update the modules list: apps > Update Apps List

Now you can see the theme when you search in the App list