# Odoo 9 admin screen is empty

Tags: odoo-9

I installed odoo 9 (see [odoo 9 theme installed in addson are missing from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011358/odoo-9-theme-installed-in-addson-are-missing-from-app) for the exact steps)

I'm following the following guide https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/themes.html to learn how to create a theme

I was able to create the theme and add a message on the screen (`Welcome in our website!` like in the tutorial)

and since then 
the admin screen is empty [image]
and any admin function either not working or logged me out

how can i debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution by installing odoo 10

https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Works smoothly but I had to `sudo su postgres` before start odd `./odoo-bin`

than I could walked-through https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/themes.html